# or statement / conditional beginning

Tags: spring-statemachine

something basic I'm missing.
Here is my pseudo scenario:

Say my flow can begin with either State A or State B.
If flow began with State A then it should transit to State B triggering event S.
If flow began with State B then it should transit to State A triggering event D.
How can I build such configuration?

Comment: You can only have one initial state but after that you could do choices and fire new events from actions. But maybe you could describe your problem you're trying to resolve as just reading your question it makes me wonder you're trying to do something you shouldn't.

Comment: thanks, i solved it. was error how i defined the sm. great work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code fot that pseudo scenario:

```
if (stateA) {
   applyStateB()
   triggerEventS()
} else if (stateB) {
   applyStateA()
   triggerEventD()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I meant using Spring StateMachine approach, using withExternal().state().target().event() .... Yesterday I find the solution. Just number of times to use withExternal() ....